# Labels above the nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the simple graph below,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,main node/.style={circle,fill=white!20,draw}, scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]   

\node[main node] [label={[label distance=1cm]30:label}] (A) {$v_1$};
\node[main node] (B) [right of=A] {$v_2$}; 
\node[main node] (C) [right of=B] {$v_3$};
\node[main node] (D) [right of=C] {$v_4$};

\draw 
(A) -- (C)
(B) -- (C)
(B) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is it possible to remove lines going through the nodes (making the inside of the nodes empty) and placing the labels above the nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're drawing a line from `A` to `C`, so that will go over `B`. If you draw from `A` to `B` to `C` to `D` you avoid that.

If by 'label' you mean the label you have already added, just change `30` to `90` (or remove `30:` altogether, above is the default). If you mean `v_i`, then add those with a label as well. In the last case you may want to change the `minimum size` of the nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,main node/.style={circle,fill=white!20,draw}, scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]   

\node[main node] [label={[label distance=1cm]90:label}] (A) {$v_1$};
\node[main node] (B) [right of=A] {$v_2$}; 
\node[main node] (C) [right of=B] {$v_3$};
\node[main node] (D) [right of=C] {$v_4$};

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,main node/.style={minimum size = .7cm,circle,fill=white!20,draw}, scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]   

\node[main node] [label={[label distance=1cm]90:label},label=$v_1$] (A) {};
\node[main node] (B) [right of=A,label=$v_2$] {}; 
\node[main node] (C) [right of=B,label=$v_3$] {};
\node[main node] (D) [right of=C,label=$v_4$] {};

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, how did you include the latex output in the post?

Comment: @cerebrou I took a screenshot and uploaded it via the button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change your code as less as possible, you can use the `backgrounds` library.

Add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` to your preamble, and change the code like this (everything else is the same):

```
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw 
(A) -- (D);
\end{scope}
```

[image]

I changed the paths (thanks Torbjørn) because the central line got thicker/weird as you repeated the paths.

Alternatively, you could use `edge` and use curved lines:

Replace your draw with:

```
\draw 
(A) edge[out=310,in=230,-] (C)
(B) -- (C) % you could use edge[out=0,in=180,-] but it's a straight line so that will do.
(B) edge[out=60,in=135,-] (D);
```

And it gets

[image]